# Xpath exclude id from a a div

Tags: xpath

I've got this xpath expression which selects a div with id called `product-details`

`//DIV[@id='product-details']`

Now the problem is that it also selects a div with id called `price` like this  `<div id="price"> £705</div>`

Which is the express to exclude the above line from the container div?

Thanks

Comment: I am unable to replicate your described issue. Please post a sample of the document in question and indicate what you're trying to select.

Comment: I'm actually using a program called Visual Web Ripper and in the documentation, it says that the program uses xpaths to select nodes in a website. Here is a link to the manual document http://manual.visualwebripper.com/ please take a look at the section called "Editing the Xpath Manually" under the title "Selection Techniques" on the left

Comment: That link doesn't work without a license for the software. Anyway; the xpath you have above should definitely *not* return the price div. I'd talk to their customer support about their xpath processor.

Comment: I'm just guessing that the price-div is contained within the product-details-div? If so, you cannot remove it using XPath, XPath can only select whole subtrees, not modify them.